# Change Storyboard Nav View Controller on app open without noticeable transition.

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a basic ui navigation view with a table view, when a user selects a name and presses the top bar next button it should go to the main ui navigation view, after this initial setup it should start on the main view controller what's the best way to go about this?....

I currently have this:
[image]

My end goal is on complete of the LoginNavController it would "push" to the new NavController and on open always go straight too the new NavController. How do I do this in a efficient (and proper?) way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with

> My end goal is on complete of the LoginNavController it would "push" to the new NavController and on open always go straight too the new NavController. How do I do this in a efficient (and proper?) way?

If what you mean is that you would like to show the login view only once, and then always show the other view controller, one possible solution would be to use a modal segue to the next navigation controller (identified by the ID modalSegue in my code snippet). Once the login view controller has achieved its goal, you could save it through the use of NSUserDefaults (these are persistent between app launches). In the `viewWillAppear` method of the login view controller you could then check the value for the relative key, and if it is set then perform directly the segue to the other navigation view controller. It would be something like:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber* result = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isSet"];

    if(result.boolValue)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalSegue" sender:self];
}
```

And to set the key once the loginViewController is done you would do something like:

```
-(void) setLoginCompleted
{        
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isSet"];
}
```

EDIT: For a smoother user experience, you could directly set the rootViewController of your application window in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate's method. In this case you would do something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MyNavController *nav =  [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavVC"];
    NSNumber* result = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isSet"];
    if(result.boolValue)
        [self.window setRootViewController:nav];
    return YES;
}
```